# How can I how extract/parse variable info from the END of a string in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, string

Example1:

> 01/28/14 Interest Earned **0.10**

Example2:

> 12/27/13 CHECKCARD 1226 LIONHEART BOOKSTORE SEATTLE WA **-25.13**

In the two examples provided, my goal is to separate out the information after the last space in the string. Put another way, I'm trying to parse the data from the RIGHT, up to the space.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SuperUser! Could you edit your question to include what methods you have tried and how you're looking to achieve this (EG. VBA Macro, or Formula)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Power Query to do that. Power Query is a free add-in from Microsoft for Excel 2010 and Excel 2013 and it is built into Excel 2016 on the Data ribbon as "Get & Transform".

Power Query has a command to split a text by delimiter and a setting to use the right-most delimiter.

Or, if you want a formula solution: calculate the length of the cell, subtract the length of the cell where all spaces have been removed, feed that number into the Right() function to return the rightmost x characters. Convert into a number by adding a zero, which will coerce a string to number if possible.

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))+0
```

Edit: Good suggestion from ThunderFrame in the comment: there could be leading/trailing spaces in the source, which can be handled like this:

```
=RIGHT(TRIM(A1),LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ","")))+0
```

Comment: I'm unsure if PowerQuery is available to home/personal users of Excel? Also, while the sample data doesn't have any trailing spaces, it might be safer to assume data might contain trailing spaces, and add some trim functions into your formula, to accommodate that.

Comment: @ThunderFrame Power Query for Excel 2010 requires a Professional Plus version. All later Excel versions can use the public flavour of Power Query that contains more connectors and functionality than a non-enterprise user will need. The public flavour of PQ does not contain connectors to Azure, AD, SharePoint, etc., but chances are that the Home/Personal Excel user does not need that, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, and such a useful thing to do. I found this solution a while back. Assuming your string is in cell A1, you can use this formula:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

Check out this SO thread for the deets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617349/excel-last-character-string-match-in-a-string

I just tried this with your test data, and it works.

*FULL DISCLOSURE:* I totally don't understand why this formula works, but it does.